# Flash in android app

Tags: android, flash

Can I use flash in my android native app?
The application is not an internet app, so it does not use HTML/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't, as of now, know a way to do this.
Which version of Android are you using?
I guess some of Androids support Flash Lite.

Please elaborate what kind of use of flash you want.

Comment: I know that Android 2.0 onwards support flash. I want to use some animations in my app. I browsed on Google and most results say that try including webview in app and embed flash in that webview. I want to know is there any other method for this?  Thanks for reply..

Comment: Why don't you try Android's own 2D animations!? there are plenty of them available!

Comment: Do you know if android supports any of animation file formats?  I have sequence of animations for an object. What will be better for animating an object, animation file or android's 2D animation in code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to incluye the .swf inside your app an then try to load it into a Webview with a simple html code.

Of course you will need flash installed on your mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can I believe - I've seen an application called .swf Player
The user would obviously require Flash 10.1 installed.
Another alternative is to write the app using Adobe Air which again requires Flash to be installed